# Does convergence along a diagonal grid imply convergence along other paths going to infinity?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples, symmetry

Suppose that for each natural $k$, we have a sequence of real numbers $a_{n,k}$, and that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n,k}=\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is independent of $k$.

Suppose furthermore that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n,n}=\alpha $ as well.

Is it true that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n,f(n)}=\alpha$, for any monotonic increasing function $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a_{n,k}= \frac{k}{n^2}$$

fixing n would definitely give you a divergent sequence while your conditions are satisfied for this double sequence.

Comment: I may need more coffee, but I'm not sure that "fixing $n$" is a possibility as the question was phrased. But letting $f(n) = n^2$, we get $a_{n, f(n)} = \frac{n^2}{n^2} = 1$, while for each fixed $k$ we have that the limit $a = 0$.

Comment: @JohnHughes I need more coffee XD
taking $ k= n^4 $ would be a good counter example if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: Right. You definitely had a good start...and my instance shows that an "f"-path doesn't always converge to the 'expected' answer, while yours now shows it can actually diverge. I think the question is now pretty-well answered. :)

Comment: On point! thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Take any $f$ such that for all $n$, $f(n) \neq n$ (for example, $f(n) = n + 1)$. Define $a_{n, k} = \begin{cases} \alpha & k \neq f(n) \\ \beta & k = f(n)\end{cases}$. Check what are $\lim\limits_k a_{n, k}$, $\lim\limits_n a_{n, n}$ and $\lim\limits_n a_{n, f(n)}$.